# How to change script wthout id via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, src

I have an html `script` tag without an id, but I need to change is it's attributes with javascript or jquery. The problem is that there are multiple scripts, all next to each other. Is there any way that by using the `$("").attr` or `document.script` operators or `(for;i++;var i)` statements I can search out a `script` with a specific Url but no id and change that script's attributes?

Comment: use `src` as selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This would target the elements `<script>` which already has an attribute `'src'` in the DOM and change its attribute.

```
var scriptUrl = "www.msn.com";
$('script[src=' + scriptUrl + ']').attr("src","new value");
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that I need to change it for a specific script out of a million without id's

Comment: what is the criteria for the selection ?

Answer (score 1):

use `src` as selector.

```
$("script[src='your-script-url-to identify']").prop('class','newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this. I sure hope this will help you.

```
var matchSrc = 'path/to/some/src',
    scripts  = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );

var i, j;

for ( i = 0, j = scripts.length; i < j; i++ ) {
    if ( matchSrc == scripts[i].getAttribute('src') ) {
        scripts[i].className = 'found-you';
        break;
    };
};
```

**UPDATE:** Corrected a silly JS error ^_^

Comment: Is it possable to replace a js src with a js file

Comment: Yeah we sort of can. `scripts[i].innerHTML = 'custom js code'`. Although first remove this `scripts[i].src = ''`. Now the biggest concern is that the browser may have already read & processed the script in question, so any change afterwards wont effect. To make sure it does the our script must run before the script to be modified.

Comment: Now I assume that the modifier script will be added at the bottom, I don't see a way you new requirement can be achieved.